# How to use multiple edit form using Html Helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I want to make multiple editing page.
But I don't know how to use `TextBoxFor()`, `TextAreaFor()`, `ValidationMessageFor()` in a `foreach` loop.

```
@foreach (var note in Model.noteList)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm()){
        @Html.Hidden("id", note.id);
        <div class="userIdArea"><b>@note.userId</b></div>  
        <div class="noteArea">@note.content</div>  
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.note.userId, new { @Value = note.userId })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(note => note.noteList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.note.content)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    }
}
```

The code above cannot set the textarea value, and I don't think it's the right way to do that.

EDIT )

I changed code like this,

```
@foreach (var note in Model.noteList)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm()){
        @Html.Hidden("note.id", note.id);
        <div class="userIdArea"><b>@note.userId</b></div>  
        <div class="noteArea">@note.content</div>  
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => note.userId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => note.content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_ => note.content)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    }
}
```

and I still have problem with using ValidationMessageFor().

I make only one content empty and submit form then it happens like this,

[image]

How should I do put ValidationMessage on right place?

[EDIT #2]

Yes, I have create form too in same view,

the View code is like this,

```
@model MemoBoard.Models.NoteViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Note</h2>
<br /><br />
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.note.userId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.note.userId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.note.userId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.note.content)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.note.content, new { rows = 4})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.note.content)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value ="Save" />
} @* //End create form *@ 

<!-- List Area -->

@foreach (var note in Model.noteList)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm()){
        @Html.Hidden("note.id", note.id);
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <div class="userIdArea"><b>@note.userId</b></div>  
        <div class="noteArea">@note.content</div>  
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => note.userId, new { id = "A"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => note.content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => note.content)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    }
}
```

And,

Model,

```
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Content is required")]
    [DisplayName("Note")]
    public string content { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User ID is required")]
    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    public string userId {get; set;}
    public Boolean isPrivate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AttachedFile> AttachedFiles { get; set; }

}
```

View Model,

```
public class NoteViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Note> noteList { get; set; }
    public Note note { get; set; }
}
```

Controller,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var notes = unitOfWork.NoteRepository.GetNotes();
    return View(new NoteViewModel(){noteList=notes.ToList(), note = new Note()});
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Note note)
{
    try
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        unitOfWork.NoteRepository.InsertNote(note);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    }catch(DataException){
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again please");
    }

    var notes = unitOfWork.NoteRepository.GetNotes();
    return View(new NoteViewModel() { noteList = notes.ToList(), note = new Note() });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this if you want (don't need to use the `model`):

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => note.userId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => note.userId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => note.content)
```

Sometimes I change the lambda variable name to `_`, to show that the `model` is not important (but it's optional if you want):

```
@Html.LabelFor(_ => note.userId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(_ => note.userId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(_ => note.content)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you review my edited question again please? I still have problem with Validation Message.

Comment: I tried it out for my self, but for me it's working =/ You must have some other code that we don't see, for instance you have a *Save* button and *Edit* button, but your code in the question has only the *Edit* button.

Comment: I edited my question again with full code, could you review my edited(#2) question again please? sorry for asking again.. Thank You

Comment: @Expertwannabe Could you possibly add the markup for the whole view?

Comment: Yes, I just replace with whole view. Thanks :)

Comment: @Expertwannabe What MVC version are you running?

Comment: @Expertwannabe And .Net4? And what version of jquery and jquery.validate? (I'm setting up a project to reflect yours.)

Comment: jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0 and Jquery 1.7.1

Comment: @Expertwannabe Ok, so I tested it out, and it works for me. But I was thinking that maybe you didn't include the jquery validation scripts in this specific view. Is the whole page reloading when you press *Save* or *Edit*? Are these file present when you view the source in your browser (in this order): *jquery-1.7.1.js*, *jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js*, *jquery.validate.js*, *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js*

Comment: Yes, you are right!, Thank you very much x100. And how the validation message were shown without jquery.validate, I thought it uses jquery.validate.

Comment: @Expertwannabe What will happen (when jquery.validate is not included) is that a request to the server will be made to your action and `ModelState.IsValid` will be `false`, because it tries to validate all properties. So the action returns the view and all the errors and writes them out.

Comment: Aha! I understand now, so the jquery.validataion will defect an error before submit to server. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over the "note" var in the for each statement your html helpers would reference that "note" var and not the model. The solution is below:

```
@foreach (var note in Model.noteList)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm()){
        @Html.Hidden("id", note.id);
        <div class="userIdArea"><b>@note.userId</b></div>  
        <div class="noteArea">@note.content</div>  
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(note => note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(note => note.userId, new { @Value = note.userId })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(note => note.userId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(note => note.noteList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(note => note.content)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give an compilation error I believe. You cannot have the same name for the foreach variable and the lambda variable.

Comment: One way around this would be to write a separate editor template for the note object, then just use `@Html.EditorFor(_ => Model.noteList)`. Asp.Net is smart enough to look into the collection and unroll the loop for you. I'm not sure how well this would work with multiple forms on a page though - wouldn't each provoke a post of the page, then requiring reloading?